# How to implement Comments functionality in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a Requirement like i have to create Comment Box where someone can post a comment and for that comment they will get some reply and again they may receive reply and so on ...
For Example:

```
{
  "Comment":"Comment 1",
  "Reply": "Reply 1", "Reply 2"
}
```

Again Reply 1 can have 'n' number of replies, I have to Map the Sub-Replies to corresponding Replies and Replies to Corresponding Comments.

Can Anyone suggest a Structure to implement this.

Comment: `"Reply": "Reply 1", "Reply 2"` Is that even a valid JSON?

Comment: No i am planning to store all Level 1 Replies for the particular Comment in a list and then store it. Now just for an example i wrote like that.